# How to get started with Microchip's PIC12 family programming?

Tags: pic, c, microchip, mplabx, pickit

I would like to start programming PIC12F683 but I have no clue how to handle I/O. Where can I find specific syntax for specific controller?

I have tried to register on their forum, but I have't received e-mail (resent registration email multiple times, no luck).

I have found programming guide on their site - PIC12F6XX/16F6XX Memory Programming Specification - http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/52053B.pdf
If required information is there, then I have some trouble to find what I want.

Might be there is related articles, step by step guides, videos?

Comment: ANSEL=0x00; TRISIO=0x00; while(1) GPIO=~GPIO; Nothing magical about that. Everything is in the skinny 176-page datasheet.

Comment: When the question was closed, I was in the process of writing up an answer with some links to tutorials.  [Here's one](http://www.best-microcontroller-projects.com/12F675.html), for the PIC12F675 which is almost identical to what you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to product page and click 'Documentation& Software" button. You will end up here -> http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?product=PIC12F683#documentation . Take a look at application notes; the majority of them contain source code in the zip file with explanation of the code given in pdf. This is the fastest way to learn application of PIC peripherals.